# ArrayOutOfBounds Exception

Tags: java, arrays, exception

```
public void delete(int index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index > _____)
    {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    {
        Node<X> current = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            current = current.getLink();
        }

        Node<X> newNode = new Node<X>();
        newNode.setLink(current.getLink());
        current.setLink(newNode);
    }
}
```

So I can't seem to figure out the logic in writing an outofbounds exception for index when using node objects. It's not like i can do head.length, so would i use a .getLink loop first to find the Null? It's not like I can do index != null either.

Comment: Check if `getLink` returns null inside the loop and throw the exception if it does?

Comment: Why are you creating a newNode when you are deleting? It looks more like an insert operation.

Comment: the newnode becomes the links after the one i deleted, then putting that back to the head link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (index < 0 || index >= sizeOfList)
{
    throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
}
```

If you have a function that computes the length of the collection.

Comment: Does that function involve a loop to iterate over each node?

Comment: yes, thats how i get it to return the size with a counter

Comment: This works, but if you don't want to iterate twice you could throw the exception inside your existing loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for the edge cases, while writing a code.
That's the best practice.

Since, you missed the edge cases, of size 0 and list full, in the mentioned example, you were getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.